# .htaccess:order not allowed here

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I am trying to put authentication for accessing my document root directory in apache2... 
Here's my config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        AccessFileName .htaccess
        DocumentRoot /home/user/workspace
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None.htaccess
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/vishu/workspace>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride AuthConfig
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
......
......

</VirtualHost>
```

here's my .htaccess file in /home/user/workspace folder:

```
<FilesMatch >
.....
</FilesMatch>

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "MY ZONE"
    #AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /home/vishu/workspace/passwordfile
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    Require valid-user
.....
...
```

Apache gives `.htaccess:order not allowed here` error and I am getting 500 error from browser.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at your `AllowOverride` directives. I had this problem too but the following config work for me:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`AllowOverride All` will probably also work, just depends on how much you want to allow.

Check out these two links for more info:

https://drupal.org/node/10133

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Comment: My problem was `Require not allowed here` and I didn't realize that `AuthConfig` is the setting you need to add to `AllowOverride` if you want `.htaccess` files to be able to add `Require` directives.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and it was due to the restrictions on my host that didn't allow me to add anything with 'Order allow,deny' or other things. So basically I had to comment out all the stuff that wasn't 'allowed' in order to get it to work.

Might want to switch hosts if this is a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're getting "''order not allowed here''" seeing as you don't have an `Order` directive in your htaccess file, but I'm guessing it's probably something in your `/` directory because you have override set to `None`.

You can try adding overrides in the `<Directory />` container, something like:

```
AllowOverride Limit
```

as per the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order)